# Assign MySQL permission based on DNS name

Tags: mysql, azure, dns, remote-access

I have two machines on Windows Azure running Ubuntu 12.04LTS: one of them runs MySQL database and the other runs other processes that need to access to the db.
Aside from the design (it's a reduction of the real configuration) I would like to know if it's possible to assign permission to machine A to connect to MySQL 5.5 server on machine B assigning its DNS name in mysql.user table.

A quick example:

Machine A

```
Runs: application code, webserver
DNS: machineA.cloudapp.net
PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS: 123.456.789.012
INTERNAL IP ADDRESS: 1.2.3.4
```

Machine B

```
Runs: MySQL server 5.5
DNS: machineB.cloudapp.net
PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS: 098.765.432.109
INTERNAL IP ADDRESS: 4.3.2.1
```

From each machine I can't ping the other one, but

```
user@machineA:~$ ping machineB.cloudapp.net
```

correctly resolves machineB's PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS.

On machineB I executed the following commands:

- connect to MySQL server
- use mysql
- grant usage on *.* to 'user'@'machineA.cloudapp.net' identified by 'password';
- grant all privileges on db_name.* to 'user'@'machineA.cloudapp.net';
- flush privileges

When I try to connect to machineB's database from machineA I get the following:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host [123.456.789.012] is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

If I replace 'user'@'machineA.cloudapp.net' with 'user'@'123.456.789.012' it works UNTIL A REBOOT.
Azure's virtual machines IPs are not static, so I cannot bind a specific address inside user table.

What can I do?

Comment: May i know how u solved this issue. i am also facing similar problem

Comment: I'm sorry but after a year sincerely I don't remember how I resolved, since I also work for another company now. If I remember right I created a virtual network inside my azure account and assigned fixed VNET IP's that don't change when a machine gets rebooted. After that I put that info inside MySQL user table. Sorry I can't help you more.
Please see this link: http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/setting-static-ip-addresses-in-a-virtual-network/

Answer (score 0):

In your current configuration you'll pay data charges if you route traffic via public IP addresses exposed from a cloud service.  Create a Virtual Network, assign your own private IP address range and then run your own internal DNS.  If either machine reboots it should always be reassigned the old IP address (assuming nothing else has been turned off or on in the meantime).  Put both machines in a single Cloud Service.

Comment: Should I add a dedicated DNS machine?

Comment: Up to you - you could run BIND (or whatever the current DNS service of choice is) on your database boxes with a primary / secondary setup across the two machines.  Depending on your goal (and desired run cost) you could choose to run another server just for DNS (I guess small linux instance could handle it, though I'd run two for resilience).